# Convert String to time using shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, powershell

I have shell script which will bring time (h:m:s)from database and compare that time with the current time to make an action depending on the result of comparing .

I get current time using this command

```
currenttime=$(date +%H%M%S);
```

the time which I received from database which is peak_time with this format 
H:M:s
so I am removed the : from that time using this code

```
 peak_time=`$peak_time' | sed s/://g `
```

and now I need to convert the last result to time using this command

```
 peak_time=$(date -d "$peak_time" +%H%M%S);
```

but I get this error

> date: invalid date ‘190000’

so please tell me how can I resolve this problem

Comment: The `+%H%M%S` part is the output format, not the input. What is your expected output?

Comment: Did you actually try leaving the `:` in before deciding to remove them? `date -d "19:00:00" '+%H%M%S'` seems to work fine...

Answer (score 1):

Your command is not correct.

First, you're trying to 'execute' the variable assignation here:

```
peak_time=`$peak_time' | sed s/://g `
```

To run this command properly you should write:

```
peak_time=$(echo $peak_time | sed 's/://g')
```

But, like some people said in the comments, you don't need more steps besides the last one:

```
peak_time=$(date -d "$peak_time" +%H%M%S)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but removing this step from your flow:
 peak_time=`$peak_time' | sed s/://g`
Will make the next step work, as you're effectively converting your time string to something like 190000 from 19:00:00 using `date` already.